# Склоняется ли идиш?

Tags: лексикография, склоняемость

Вот что находим на [Грамота.ру:](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?game=x&all=x&word=%E8%E4%E8%F8)

> *Орфографический словарь*
>   идиш, -а, нескл., м. и неизм.
>
> *Большой толковый словарь*
>   ИДИШ, -а; м. [нем. judisch - еврейский] Язык части евреев (живущих в Европе, Америке, Южной Африке и Израиле), имеющий в своей основе немецкие диалекты. Говорить на идише. Владеть идишем.

Так склоняется ли идиш?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вики говорит, что в  русском языке слово «идиш» допустимо использовать в качестве как склоняемого, так и несклоняемого существительного. https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/10525

Он говорил на языке идиш, он говорил на идише.

Влияние языка идиш, влияние идиша на одесские диалекты.

Видимо, изменяемость - более современная тенденция.

Answer (score 2):

В словаре Ушакова (**1935-1940**):
[И́ДИШ](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/819006/%D0%98%D0%94%D0%98%D0%A8) и йидиш, нескл., муж.

В орфографическом словаре под ред. С. И. Ожегова и А. Б. Шапиро (печатный вариант, 110000 слов, **1957**): **и́диш**, -а, *тв.* -шем.
(Возможно, это и есть "время перемен".)

А вот в современный [русский орфографический словарь](https://lopatin.academic.ru/43954) (**1999**), как мне кажется, просто вкралась ошибка: нельзя написать **и́диш, -а** [Р. п.] и утверждать, что слово «нескл.»